# Star pattern left Pascal arrow with stem in java

Tags: java, if-statement

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ******************
*******************
 ******************
  ***
   **
    *
```

I am trying to print this pattern in Java.Its for an assignment and we have to  use if,else statements to print the above pattern.

```
class fulldesign7
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int star=0;
        int space=5;
        for(int i=1;i<=9;i++)
        {
            if(i<=5)
            {
                space--;
                star++;
            }
            else if(i==4||i==5||i==6)
            {
                star=star+10;
            }
            else
            {
                space++;
                star--;
            }
            for(int j=1;j<=space;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for(int k=1;k<=star;k++)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I've come up with so far. But the if statement and else statement clash.

Comment: I did but it wasn't anywhere near what I was trying to do

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: this is what I have come up with:-class fulldesign7
{
public static void main(String[ ] args)
{
int star=0;
int space=5;
for(int i=1;i<=9;i++)
{
if(i<=5)
{
space--;
star++;
}
else if(i==4||i==5||i==6)
{
star=star+10;
}
else
{
space++;
star--;
}
for(int j=1;j<=space;j++)
{
System.out.print(" ");
}
for(int k=1;k<=star;k++)
{
System.out.print("*");
}
System.out.println();
}
}
}

Comment: Add your code and actual output not just the desired output so that it is easy for people to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I broke up your logic to simplify it.

```
public class fulldesign7
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int star=0;
        int space=5;

        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            if (i <= 4)
            {
                space--;
                star++;
            }
            else // if (i >= 5)
            {
                space++;
                star--;
            }

            if (i == 3)
            {
                star += 10;
            }
            else if (i == 6)
            {
                star -= 10;
            }

            for(int j=0; j<space; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            for(int j=0; j<star; j++)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

You need two separate if else statements implement the logic of:

- the arrow head.
- the arrow tail.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the [star +=10] and           
 [star -=10]statements. Thanks a ton

Comment: `star += 10` is the same as `star = star + 10`

Answer (score 0):

I think you could separate the arrow into the point and the tail, what I mean is first try to work out how to print this:

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
 ****
  ***
   **
    *
```

Then add the stars for the tail on lines 3, 4, and 5

So first make a method to print a line given a number of spaces and stars and if we add the tail to it:

```
private static void printLine(int spaces, int stars, boolean addTail) {
    for (int i = 0; i < spaces; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < stars; i++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }

    if (addTail) {
        System.out.println("**************");
    } else {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Then add stars and remove spaces up to line 5, then reverse for the remaining lines. Add the tail on lines 3, 4, and 5:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    int spaces = 5;
    int stars = 0;

    for (int line = 0; line < 9; line++) {
        if (line<5) {
            spaces --;
            stars ++;
        } else {
            spaces ++;
            stars --;
        }

        boolean addTail = line >= 3 && line <=5;

        printLine(spaces, stars, addTail);
    }

}
```

**NOTE:** You can also try to be more clever and notice 2 things:

- The number of spaces is the absolute value of (line - 4)
- The number of stars is always 5 minus the number of spaces

So the main could also be written as follows:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    for (int line = 0; line < 9; line++) {
        int spaces = Math.abs(line - 4);
        boolean addTail = line >= 3 && line <=5;
        printLine(spaces, 5-spaces, addTail);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't actually do it that way. Have to use an if statement.

Comment: @AbdulHannanChishti It was a bit of a joke, see my edited answer for a real solution